# Firebase Realtime DB pagination

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination, filtering

I am filtering products based on brand. I am able to get the id of the last item and use it to get another list upon clicking on load button. 
However when products from the particular brand are exhausted it keeps loading products from other brands too.

```
firebase.database().ref('products').orderByChild('brand')
            .startAt(brand, lastKey)
            .limitToFirst(31)
            .once("value", function(snapshot){
                var data = snapshot.val()
                ...
})
```

I have another pagination setup for the categories and it works perfectly. Stops exactly after it exhausts all products from the particular category.

```
firebase.database().ref('products').orderByChild('category/'+type)
                .startAt(type, lastKey)
                .limitToFirst(31)
                .once("value", function(snapshot){
                    var data = snapshot.val()
                    ...
})
```

I am thinking there might the problem on how I order the items based on brand. While brand holds a string value the category holds object. 
[image: Realtime DB schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `orderByChild().startAt()` filter, which means Firebase orders the results by the property you indicate, and then starts returning results from the node you indicate. Since you don't specify any end criteria, it keeps returning results until it reaches the end of the list.

If you want to only have child nodes whose `brand` value matches the value you specify in `startAt()`, you should also include an `endAt()` condition.

Something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('products').orderByChild('brand')
        .startAt(brand, lastKey)
        .endAt(brand+'\uf8ff')
        .limitToFirst(31)
```

The `\uf8ff` is just the last printable Unicode character, which means the list stops after that brand.

Comment: That's it. Thanks so much again Frank. That is exactly what I needed. It didn't occur to me that without endAt it would keep on going even tho startAt specifies the value in the brand field.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that the first paragraph of my answer explains why it keeps going. I short, the method is called `startAt()` and not `startsWith`.:)